# How can I Embed BaseTool to winform in ArcObjects?

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, c#, add-in

I am new to C# and still doing research. I open a windows form from a dockablewindow menu in ArcMap. I also have a button in WindowsForm, and when I click this button, I want to draw a feature on the map (point, polygon, line... whatever).

I think I should add a basetool and define the guid that basetool has as currenttool. I'm trying to do this using `ICommandItem` for this but I'm getting an error.

It returns null because it cannot find the Guid specified in the code.

BaseTool.cs:

```
namespace MaksAddIn
{
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Tool1.
/// </summary>
[Guid("03e2069c-7c3f-4156-aeda-36aa3c936221")] //using this guid
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ProgId("MaksAddIn.Tool1")]
public sealed class Tool1 : BaseTool
{
    protected IApplication m_Application;
    public ICommandItem RollbackTool { get; set; }
    private IHookHelper m_hookHelper;
    public IMxDocument m_mxDoc;
    public MxDocument m_mxDocument;
    public Map m_map;
    public PageLayout m_pageLayout;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
    public IFeatureClass featureClass;
    public Tool1()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Define values for the public properties
        //
       }
    public override void OnMouseDown(int Button, int Shift, int X, int Y)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(X.ToString(), Y.ToString());
    }
```

Winform.cs:

```
  private void Click(object sender, EventArgs arg)
    {
        IApplication _mApplication = ArcMap.Application;
        ICommandBars documentBars = _mApplication.Document.CommandBars;
        UID cmdID = new UIDClass();
        cmdID.Value = "{03e2069c-7c3f-4156-aeda-36aa3c936221}";
        ICommandItem cmdItem = documentBars.Find(cmdID); //cmdItem null error is here
        MessageBox.Show(cmdItem.ToString());
        
        _mApplication.CurrentTool = cmdItem;

    }
```

does not find the specified guid in the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need to specify the two optional parameters to the `Find` method: `documentBars.Find(cmdID, false, false);`

From the [Documentation](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#ICommandBars_Find.htm):

- *noRecurse* Use False to search all menus and toolbars for the item; otherwise use True. [Optional]
- *noCreate* Use False if you want the item to get instantiated if it isn't already; otherwise use True. [Optional]

Alternatively, if you are writing an Add-in, you can add a tool by right clicking on the project > Add New Item > ArcGIS Desktop Add-ins > Add-In Component > Add > Select the *Tool* component. Then, use `new UIDClass { Value = ThisAddIn.IDs.YourTool }`